# Filtering a dataframe by multiple conditions and creating a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to filter a dataframe by 2 conditions. For every row in "Sub-Segment" column that equals "Belux CCLM" and if the value in column "CV_LIF" is between 0 and 26999 create a new column labeled "B"  and set the row as '

But I am getting an error

```
'float' object is not subscriptable
```

```
def get_CV(row):
    if row['Sub-Segment']== 'Belux CCLM' and row['CV_LIF'] >= 0 and row['CV_LIF']<=26999:
        return '<$27K'
    if row['Sub-Segment']== 'Belux CCLM' and row['CV_LIF'] >=27000:
        return '<$27K'
    if row['Sub-Segment']== 'Belux CCLM' and row['CV_LIF']== ' ':
        return " "
df['B'] = df['CV_LIF'].apply(lambda x: get_CV(x))
```

Comment: Adding `axis=1` to the `apply` function should do the trick.

Comment: df['B'] = df['CV_LIF'].apply(lambda x: get_CV(x),axis=1) --- like so? This didn't work

Comment: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: You should also do `df.apply(...)` so that your function will receive the whole row and not just the value in column CV_LIF